# Determine thread created time in WinDbg with user-mode dump

Tags: debugging, windbg

How to determine the time thread was created in WinDbg with user-mode dump.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!runaway` command allows you to display the elapsed time since a thread was created. From the documentation:

> !runaway [Flags] Parameters
>
> Flags  Specifies the kind of information to be displayed. Flags can be
>   any combination of the following bits. The default value is 0x1.
>
> Bit 0 (0x1)  Causes the debugger to show the amount of user time
>   consumed by each thread.
>
> Bit 1 (0x2)  Causes the debugger to show the amount of kernel time
>   consumed by each thread.
>
> Bit 2 (0x4)  Causes the debugger to show the amount of time that has
>   elapsed since each thread was created.